# How can I call a dll form another dll written in cpp without it crashing on me

Tags: c++, dll, crash, autoit

I am trying to call a dll form a dll I worte in cpp, problem is it crashes when it calls the other dll. I call the very fist dll from an autoit program that I worte. This is the first dll written in cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h> // this is where MessageBox function resides(Autoit also uses this function)
#include <windows.h>
#include "basicdll.h" // We include our header file which contains function declarations and other instructions

extern "C" // Again this extern just solves c/c++ compatability [b]Make sure to use it because Autoit wont open dll for usage without it![/b]
{
//typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(int x1, int y1, int right, int bottom, char findImage, void* HBMP ); 
typedef int* (__stdcall *f_funci)(int x1, int y1, int right, int bottom, char findImage, void* HBMP );

   DECLDIR int Add( int a, int b )
   {
      return( a + b ); // Finally we define our basic function that just is a sum of 2 ints and hence returns int(c/c++ type)
   }

   DECLDIR void Function( void )
   {
      std::cout << "DLL Called! Hello AutoIt!" << std::endl; // This silly function will just output in our Autoit script "Dll Called!"
      MessageBox(0, TEXT("DLL from Autoit"), TEXT("Simple Dll..."),0);  // Use good old Message Box inside Windows Api Functions but this time with your own dll }
   }

   DECLDIR int Recognize(  int x1, int y1, int right, int bottom, char findImage, void* HBMP ){
   std::cout << "DLL Called! Hello AutoIt!" << std::endl; // This silly function will just output in our Autoit script "Dll Called!"
      MessageBox(0, TEXT("DLL from Autoit"), TEXT("Simple Dl22l..."),0);  
       // Use 

       HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
    //MYPROC ProcAdd; 
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE; 

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("D:\\Downloads\\SmartGuy\\SmartGuy\\fol\\imgsearch.dll")); 

    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.

    if (hinstLib != NULL) 
    { 
        std::cout << "DLL Called! Hello AutoIt!" << std::endl; // This silly function will just output in our Autoit script "Dll Called!"
      MessageBox(0, TEXT("hinstLib != NULL"), TEXT("Simple Dll..."),0);  // 

    //MYPROC  ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "ImageSearchEx"); 
      f_funci ImageSearchEx = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "ImageSearchEx");

        // If the function address is valid, call the function.

        if (NULL != ImageSearchEx) 
        {

        std::cout << "DLL Called! Hello AutoIt!" << std::endl; // This silly function will just output in our Autoit script "Dll Called!"
      MessageBox(0, TEXT("NULL != ProcAdd"), TEXT("Simple Dll..."),0);  // 

            fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
          int result=0;
          ImageSearchEx (x1,y1,right,bottom,findImage, HBMP); 

          int index1 = 1;
std::string test1 = std::to_string(static_cast<long long>(result));
MessageBoxA(NULL, test1.c_str(), "testx", MB_OK);

          MessageBox(0, TEXT("DLL from Autoittt"), TEXT("ok"),0);

        }
        // Free the DLL module.

        fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib); 
    } 

    // If unable to call the DLL function, use an alternative.
    if (! fRunTimeLinkSuccess) 
        printf("Message printed from executable\n"); 

    return 1;
   }

}
```

here is the header file :

```
#ifndef _DLL_TUTORIAL_H_
#define _DLL_TUTORIAL_H_  // This is basically to tell compiler that we want to include this code only once(incase duplication occurs), you include it in .cpp file(which we will soon do)
#include <iostream>       // Inlcude basic c++ standard library output header(this is used for output text on the screen in our code)

#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
#include <sstream>


// We #define __declspec(dllexport) as DECLDIR macro so when compiler sees DECLDIR it will just take it as __declspec(dllexport)(say that DECLDIR is for readability)
// Note that there is also __declspec(dllimport) for internal linking with others programs but since we just need to export our functions so we can use them with Autoit, thats all we need!


extern "C"  // this extern just wraps things up to make sure things work with C and not only C++
{

// Here we declare our functions(as we do with normal functions in c header files, our cpp file will define them(later). Remember that DECLDIR is just a shortcut for __declspec(dllexport)

   DECLDIR int Add( int a, int b ); 
   DECLDIR void Function( void );
   DECLDIR int Recognize(  int x1, int y1, int right, int bottom, char findImage, void* HBMP  );

#endif // closing #ifndef _DLL_TUTORIAL_H_
}
```

now this file was compiled to dll as well, called basicdll.dll and I am calling it from and autoit.au3 program :

```
$dllF1 = DllOpen("basicdll.dll")
DllCall($dllF1, "int:cdecl", "Recognize", "int", $x1, "int", $y1, "int", $right, "int", $bottom,"str", $findImage, "ptr", $HBMP)

DllCall($dllF1, "none", "Function")
```

everything works fine until the program reaches this line in the cpp file I worte:

```
ImageSearchEx (x1,y1,right,bottom,findImage, HBMP);
```

after this the program crashes;
now, ImageSearchEx is function in imgsearch.dll, I haven't wrote it myself. But I know how to use it, here is a successful use of the function in autoit:

```
$result = DllCall($LibDir & "\imgsearch.dll", "str", "ImageSearchEx", "int", $x1, "int", $y1, "int", $right, "int", $bottom, "str", $findImage, "ptr", $HBMP)
```

$HBMP is an image handler for the image $findImage
I know I probably did something wrong , how to fix this, btw I am noob in cpp so go easy.

Comment: are you sure `typedef int* (__stdcall *f_funci)(int x1, int y1, int right, int bottom, char findImage, void* HBMP );` is correct?

Comment: nope not sure at all, this is what I have seen here on this site, someone suggested it, can you correct it please?

Comment: I don't know how to correct is, as I have not written it either. Maybe you are able to find some documentation or a header file?

Comment: ho u mean the function signature? I think it's correct, I meant the part of typedef int* (__stdcall *f_funci)

Comment: The most important part is `__stdcall`, if that is wrong, it will crash. You have to look in the documentation which calling convention is used.